# Xcode table view from array splitted

Tags: iphone, xcode, arrays, tableview

I'm trying to get a tableview starting from a string in this format "name1,link1,name2,link2..."
So what i'm actually doing is this:

-Get the string and put links and names into an array, then split the array into two lesser ones by the position of the objects

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSString *dataString = @"a,www.google.it,b,www.apple.it,c,www.youtube.it";
dataArray = [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
for (int i=0; i<[dataArray count]; i++) {
    if (i%2==0) {
        [dataArrayName addObject:[dataArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    else {
        [dataArrayLink addObject:[dataArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

-Set up the table view

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

{
return [dataArrayName count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"myCell";

// Try to retrieve from the table view a now-unused cell with the given identifier.
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

// If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier.
if (cell == nil) {
    // Use the default cell style.
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
}

// Set up the cell.
NSString *cellName = [dataArrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellName;

return cell;
}
```

But when i run the application the view with the tableview is clear (there are empty rows)
What's the problem?

Comment: In IB, did you correctly connect the dataSource and delegate outlets of your table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you initialized dataArrayName and dataArrayLink (ie, at some point, before you started adding objects to it, did you say `dataArrayName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` or an equivalent?

Comment: You may have declared it there (`NSMutableArray *dataArrayName;`), but did you actually initialize it in the .m? They're not the same thing in Objective-C.